# java/jackson - don't serialize wrapping class

Tags: java, json, list, jackson, wrapper

When serializing a list of string with Jackson library, it provides correctly a JSON array of strings:

```
<mapper>.writeValue(System.out, Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));

[ "a", "b", "c" ]
```

However, the strings are wrapped/enclosed by a class in our code:

```
public static class StringWrapper {
    protected final String s;

    public String getS() {
        return s;
    }

    public StringWrapper(final String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }
}
```

When serializing a list of "string wrapers", I would like to have the same output as above. Now I get:

```
<mapper>.writeValue(System.out, Arrays.asList(new StringWrapper("a"), new StringWrapper("b"), new StringWrapper("c")));

[ {
  "s" : "a"
}, {
  "s" : "b"
}, {
  "s" : "c"
} ]
```

What is the most convenient method to do this? If possible, deserializing should work also.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `@JsonValue` on your single getter

```
@JsonValue
public String getS() {
    return s;
}
```

From the javadoc,

> Marker annotation similar to javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue that
>   indicates that results of the annotated "getter" method (which means
>   signature must be that of getters; non-void return type, no args) **is
>   to be used as the single value to serialize for the instance**. Usually
>   value will be of a simple scalar type (String or Number), but it can
>   be any serializable type (Collection, Map or Bean).

Comment: This seems to work perfectly! Thank you. I'll accept this as answer.

Comment: I had a class `class MyClass { private Map<String, String> props; ... @JsonValue public Map<String, String> getProps() { return this.props } }` Worked as advertised... The serialization of an instance with 2 entries properly showed `{ "key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2" }`! Thanks!

Comment: Works for Enums as well, e.g. `public enum Operation {
 TEST("test"), REMOVE("remove"), ADD("add"), REPLACE("replace"), MOVE("move"), COPY("copy");

 private String value;

 Operation(String value) {
  this.value = value;
 }

 @Override
 @JsonValue
 public String toString() {
  return value;
 }

}`

Answer (score 3):

I see two possible options. If you *own* the `StringWrapper` class you can simply add the `@JsonValue` annotation on the getter.

```
@JsonValue
public String getS() { return s; }
```

If you are not allowed to change the object the following streaming solution works as well:

```
mapper.writeValueAsString(listOfStringWrappers.stream().map(sw -> sw.getS()).toArray());
```